# How to click on button in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running scripts using **serenity jbehave**. I need to click on continue button. Here I am identifying it by **dynamic xpath**. But it is not responding through script but manually its working fine.

I have identified it as below

```
Xpath=//input[@value='continue']
```

And performed click operation.

is there any way to solve this issue

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or it's just not working? Check if there are any other inputs with the values 'continue'

Comment: If its just not working, there may be a margin surrounding the button. The WebDriver will click the top left of an element. So if there is a margin surrounding the outside of the button, then the driver may be clicking there instead of the actual button.

Answer (score 1):

In fact most of the time the problem of not being able to click on the button is not related to you having misspelled your code and if the page is not fully loaded try to do "A" mode if you continue with a mistake do the "B"

A mode:
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='continue']"));`

B mode: 
`WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait (driver,10);
wait.until(expectedconditions.elementtobeclickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='continue']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='continue']"))`

Comment: Yes I have tried but finally its environment issue our code is correct thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these below mentioned code to click on button.

Before click to the button, provide few seconds of `wait` so your driver may able to find the webelement.

For wait, I'm using `explicit wait` method.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);   // wait for 5 seconds
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='continue'][@type='button']"))));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='continue'][@type='button']")).click();
```

> OR

Try to click on button using `java-script executor` method.

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='continue'][@type='button']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling the browser so that the button is "visible" before executing the "element.click"